# Creating ellipses with the Chipmunk Physics Engine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I need to create an ellipse with a width of 52 pixels and a height of 47 pixels. Using the Chipmunk engine, I've found that you can create circles with a certain radius, as well as polygons. I'm new to working with Chipmunk, and the documentation for the engine is quite brief.

How do I create ellipses in Chipmunk? I'm currently working with iPhones, using Objective-c and cocos2d.

I know it may seem useless to go in these details but I need to create it as precise as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [PhysicsEditor](http://www.physicseditor.de) to design any shape.

If you already have an image of an ellipse, then you can use that image to allow PhysicsEditor to trace the borders of the image. Either way this is a lot easier than actually programming the shape.

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation from Chipmunk's author, slembcke, seems to be “approximate it using a polygon”.  [See this forum post.](http://chipmunk-physics.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1424)

If a polygon approximation isn't good enough, you will have to modify Chipmunk to add a new ellipse shape type, because it doesn't have support for ellipses.  And adding support for ellipses is probably a significant amount of work.